# Tensorflow JS GAN model never learns

Tags: tensorflow.js

I am trying to port the Python DCGAN MNIST Code Lab example (https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/generative/dcgan) to Tensorflow.js. The generator model should be able to create images of handwritten digits similar to the MNIST sample data.

My code runs without error but I'm facing two main problems.

1. The training process is vastly slower than the Python example. E.g., JS in the browser vs running the Python example in Google's Code Lab.
2. My Generator model never gets to the point where it actually generates hand written numbers.

It learns to the point where it generates grid-looking images but never seems to learn much past that.

[image]

I believe that the models are a 1:1 port. Here are my models.

```
// discriminator model
let dModel = tf.sequential();
const IMAGE_WIDTH = 28;
const IMAGE_HEIGHT = 28;
const IMAGE_CHANNELS = 1;

dModel.add(
tf.layers.conv2d({inputShape: [IMAGE_WIDTH, IMAGE_HEIGHT, IMAGE_CHANNELS], kernelSize: [5,5], filters: 64, strides: [2,2], activation: "relu",
    kernelInitializer: "varianceScaling"
  })
);

dModel.add(tf.layers.leakyReLU())
dModel.add(tf.layers.dropout(0.3))

dModel.add(
tf.layers.conv2d({kernelSize: [5,5], filters: 128, strides: [2,2],
    activation: "relu", kernelInitializer: "varianceScaling"
  })
);

dModel.add(tf.layers.leakyReLU())
dModel.add(tf.layers.dropout(0.3))
dModel.add(tf.layers.flatten());

const NUM_OUTPUT_CLASSES = 1;
dModel.add(tf.layers.dense({units: NUM_OUTPUT_CLASSES}))
```

```
// generator model
let gModel = tf.sequential();
gModel.add(tf.layers.dense({units: 7 * 7 * 256,inputShape: [100], useBias: false}));
gModel.add(tf.layers.batchNormalization());
gModel.add(tf.layers.leakyReLU());

gModel.add(tf.layers.reshape({ targetShape: [7, 7, 256] }));

gModel.add(tf.layers.conv2dTranspose({filters: 128, kernelSize: [5, 5], strides: [1, 1], useBias: false, padding: "same"}));
gModel.add(tf.layers.batchNormalization());
gModel.add(tf.layers.leakyReLU());

gModel.add(tf.layers.conv2dTranspose({filters: 64, kernelSize: [5, 5], strides: [2, 2], useBias: false,padding: "same" }));
gModel.add(tf.layers.batchNormalization());
gModel.add(tf.layers.leakyReLU());

gModel.add(tf.layers.conv2dTranspose({filters: 1,kernelSize: [5, 5], strides: [2, 2], useBias: false,padding: "same", activation: "tanh" }));
```

The loss functions are where I can't find a JS equilivent to Gradient Tape, so I have designed them a little differently.

The Python example uses:

```
cross_entropy = tf.keras.losses.BinaryCrossentropy(from_logits=True)

def discriminator_loss(real_output, fake_output):
    real_loss = cross_entropy(tf.ones_like(real_output), real_output)
    fake_loss = cross_entropy(tf.zeros_like(fake_output), fake_output)
    total_loss = real_loss + fake_loss
    return total_loss

def generator_loss(fake_output):
    return cross_entropy(tf.ones_like(fake_output), fake_output)

def train_step(images):
    noise = tf.random.normal([BATCH_SIZE, noise_dim])

    with tf.GradientTape() as gen_tape, tf.GradientTape() as disc_tape:
      generated_images = generator(noise, training=True)

      real_output = discriminator(images, training=True)
      fake_output = discriminator(generated_images, training=True)

      gen_loss = generator_loss(fake_output)
      disc_loss = discriminator_loss(real_output, fake_output)

    gradients_of_generator = gen_tape.gradient(gen_loss, generator.trainable_variables)
    gradients_of_discriminator = disc_tape.gradient(disc_loss, discriminator.trainable_variables)

    generator_optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(gradients_of_generator, generator.trainable_variables))
    discriminator_optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(gradients_of_discriminator, discriminator.trainable_variables))
```

Where as I used optimizer.minimize. I'm not sure if this is maybe overtraining the discriminator and causing the issue or not.

Even though it seems like duplicate calls to model.predict inside the loss functions, I had do it this way, otherwise I got an error `Please make sure the operations that use variables are inside the function f passed to minimize()`

```
function trainStep() {
  const noise = tf.randomNormal([BATCH_SIZE, 100])
  const fakeLabels = tf.ones([BATCH_SIZE], 'int32')
  const realLabels = tf.zeros([BATCH_SIZE], 'int32')

  const dLossCalc = () => {
    const fakeImages = gModel.predict(noise).add(1).div(2)
    let realImages = data.nextTrainBatch(BATCH_SIZE).xs
    realImages = realImages.reshape([BATCH_SIZE, IMAGE_WIDTH, IMAGE_HEIGHT, 1])
    realImages = realImages.sub(127.5).div(127.5)     //normalize to 1, -1

    const fakeLogits = dModel.predict(fakeImages).reshape([BATCH_SIZE])
    const realLogits = dModel.predict(realImages).reshape([BATCH_SIZE])

    const fakeLoss = tf.losses.sigmoidCrossEntropy(fakeLabels.mul(0.98), fakeLogits)
    const realLoss = tf.losses.sigmoidCrossEntropy(realLabels, realLogits)
    const totalLoss = fakeLoss.add(realLoss)
    console.log('Disc Loss ' + totalLoss.dataSync())
    return totalLoss
  }

  const gLossCalc = () => {
    const fakeImages = gModel.predict(noise).add(1).div(2)
    const logits = dModel.predict(fakeImages).reshape([BATCH_SIZE])
    const loss = tf.losses.sigmoidCrossEntropy(fakeLabels, logits) 
    console.log('Gen Loss ' + loss.dataSync())
    return loss
  }

  dOptimizer.minimize(dLossCalc)
  gOptimizer.minimize(gLossCalc)
}
```

At this point I've spent hours and would appreciate any help.

The two main things that I couldn't find an equivalent for were Gradient Tape / Apply Gradients and the tf.keras.losses.BinaryCrossentropy loss function. I am using sigmoidCrossEntropy instead.

Here's a fully working codepen example if anyone is willing to have a look:
https://codepen.io/freeman-g/pen/KKpRyyX?editors=0010

As a side note, I noticed that applyGradients is not documented in the Tensorflow.js API docs and have opened a related GitHub issue: https://github.com/tensorflow/tfjs/issues/2897

Answer (score 1):

Execution speed might be down to ensuring that your browser has proper access to the GPU - you may need to install a bunch of nVidia CUDA drivers.  I'm on windows and the browser/driver setup was fairly involved.  It's worth doing, even my bargain-basement GT 1030 GPU was a 5-6x speedup over using my CPU.

Binary Cross Entropy is available in `tf.metrics.binaryCrossEntropy` instead of  `tf.keras.losses.BinaryCrossentropy`

It looks like because of the python syntax that `with tf.GradientTape()` is using, it's not quite possible to have the same syntax.  Based on my reading, it looks like `with tf.GradientTape()` is basically making an anonymous function that gets called a bunch of times by the GradientTape object in order to actually determine the gradient.

The `tfjs` equivalent to GradientTape appears to be tf.grads (useful: `tfjs-core/dist/ops/conv2d_transpose_test.js` has a bunch of tests that include python and JS versions of the same tasks).  You pass in an anonymous function, which then gets called when you want to determine gradients.

Here's code that ports the python tf.GradientTape() documentation example into JS - it gets the same result.  Note: I am not a python developer, so I may have misinterpreted some of the python stuff.

```
  // python example from https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/GradientTape:
  //     x = tf.constant(3.0)
  //     with tf.GradientTape() as g:
  //         g.watch(x)
  //         y = x * x
  //     dy_dx = g.gradient(y, x)   <-- gets slope of y per x
  //     print(dy_dx)               <-- prints "tf.Tensor(6.0, shape=(), dtype=float32)"


  // tfjs version:
  // myGradFunction is the equivalent of the inside of the `with` section - it squares the incoming Tensor
  // args is the array of Tensors I pass in when I call getGrad later.
  const myGradFunction = (...args:Tensor[]):Tensor => {
    const x = args[0];
    return x.mul(x);
  } 

  // this is basically the same as "with tf.GradientTape()" - it builds a manager and 
  // feeds it the anonymous function it will eventually use to determine gradient.
  // the "as any" is because tfjs's typescript doesn't appear to be perfect or I'm dumb.
  const getGrad = tf.grads(myGradFunction as any);

  const xs = [
    tf.tensor(3, [1]), // tf.constant(3.0) more or less
  ];
  const gradients = getGrad(xs); // this will trigger a bunch of calls to myGradFunction

  // spit out the result
  gradients.forEach((grad) => grad.print());
```

I'm working on doing the GAN example in JS myself, will update this post with a github link if I manage it.